# How to customize a frame with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to understand how tkinter works. I have this simple program:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = tk.Frame(master, height=100, width=500, bg="#FFFFFF", bd=10)
        frame.grid()
        self.button = tk.Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=frame.quit)
        self.button.grid()

root = tk.Tk()
app=Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

when I run the program I get a window, but the options I specified for the frame (height, width ...) are not working. Where is my mistake? Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `grid_propagate` to zero. This stops the frame from resizing to the size of the button.

After `frame.grid()`, add `frame.grid_propagate(0)`.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = tk.Frame(master, height=100, width=500, bg="#FFFFFF", bd=10)
        frame.grid()
        frame.grid_propagate(0)
        self.button = tk.Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=frame.quit)
        self.button.grid()

root = tk.Tk()
app=Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `grid_propagate` is a bad suggestion for someone who is learning tkinter. It is almost never the proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter widgets are designed to "shrink to fit" their child widgets. This is almost always what you want, if your goal is to write a GUI that is responsive to changes in fonts, resolution, and sizes. In other words, you haven't made a mistake, tkinter is behaving exactly as it was designed to behave.

While there are ways to force a window to a specific size, I strongly recommend against it. If you instead focus on making the inner widgets the proper size, your frames and main window will all intelligently resize to make sure everything fits. You should almost never need to give explicit pixel sizes to anything (except, perhaps, a canvas).

Comment: Thank you Bryan for your suggestion!